# Nested list iterations

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have some list in Python, with nested lists named otherElem which looks like:

```
otherElem=[[list1],[list2],...[list_n]]
```

What I need is to create new list which will perform some operations (that's j.Mirror is irrelevant, can be anything) and create a new list which will maintain order and format of previous list. I've tried this, but didn't succeed. I'm totally new in programming, sorry for typos (if any)

```
for i in otherElem:
        for j in i:
            j=j.Mirror(mirPlane)
            newList.Add(j)
        newList2.Add(newList)
```

Comment: What was the erroneous output, give that it didn't look like what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop can easily be written as a list comprehension:

```
[ j.Mirror(mirPlane) for j in i ]
```

And so can the outer loop:

```
[ <inner part here> for i in otherElem ]
```

Putting it together, we get a nested list comprehension:

```
newList2 = [
  [ j.Mirror(mirPlane) for j in i ]
  for i in otherElem
]
```

Comment: I'm not programmer, but this solution looking very nice (and working also). Tnx

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with nested list comprehension, something like this.

```
otherElem=[[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

l = [[an_elem * 2 for an_elem in inner_list] for inner_list in otherElem]

print l
```

Result is,

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [10, 12, 14, 16], [18, 20, 22, 24]]
```

Here, the operation on each element is multiply by 2. in your case it's `j.Mirror(mirPlane)`, which I don't know, what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are right; a list comprehension is probably the best way to do this in Python. Meanwhile, it specifically looks like what's wrong with your listed solution is that it needs to create a new list each time it looks at an inner list. It should look like:

```
new_list_of_lists = [] 
for old_list in old_list_of_lists:
   new_list = []
   new_list_of_lists.append(new_list)
   for old_item in old_list:
      new_item = transformation(old_item) 
      new_list.append(new_item)
```

Those seven lines are completely equivalent to the much shorter nested list comprehensions, so you can see why those comprehensions are preferable!

Comment: Tnx, like that old school method :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `operator` to invoke a nice nested call.

```
import operator

upper = operator.methodcaller('upper')
list =[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]
print [map(upper, sub_list) for sub_list in list]
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']]
```